# Java Math Sqrt gives NaN

Tags: java, android, math

I searched on the website and I didn't find a problem like this
my problem is that in my android application when I do so :

```
String ET6 = et6.getText().toString();
String ET7 = et7.getText().toString();
String ET8 = et8.getText().toString();
int IET6 = Integer.parseInt(ET6);
int IET7 = Integer.parseInt(ET7);
int IET8 = Integer.parseInt(ET8);
double sqrt1 = (IET7 ^ 2) - 4 *(IET6 * IET8);
sqrt1 = Math.sqrt(sqrt1);
```

I get a NaN value
What is wrong with the calculation ?

sqrt = 3^2 - 4*2*1

sqrt = 9 - 8

sqrt = 1

Then the sqrt root should be 1

Comment: `3^2`, the `^` doesn´t really do a power operation here, it´s a `XOR`

Answer (score 7):

The problem here is that `3^2` is not `3²`.

Instead, it is 3 XOR 2.

```
  11 //3
 ^10 //2
 ----
  01 //1
```

So the result is a negative number (1-8 = -7), and sqrt of that is NaN.

So, you should either do `3*3` or `(int)Math.pow(3,2)`

Comment: I changed it to be IET7 * IET7

Answer (score 2):

If the argument is NaN or less than zero, then the result of Math.sqrt(argument) is NaN.  Source java documentation [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#sqrt(double))

Answer (score 2):

You are using XOR. You should use pow function from Math class:

```
double sqrt1 = Math.pow(IET7, 2) - 4 *(IET6 * IET8);
```